# What accounts for the apparent lack of biodiversity in "bamboo forests"?

Tags: ecology

While hiking on the Hawaiian island of Maui, I passed from a forest with normal variety in trees and other flora, to a "[bamboo forest](https://www.paradise-found-in-maui.com/bamboo-forest.html)" area in which the only plants that I could see were bamboo.

This was surprising to me! Why does only bamboo (appear to) grow in this area?

The assumption I'm making is that bamboo forests happen elsewhere in the world, not just in Maui.

Comment: Mostly the fast growth shades other trees, lateral rhyzomes, mats of undregradable leaves, other factors may contribute. It invades ecosystems mostly vecause its cylinder hollow geometry gives it a massive height / to weight and sunlight monopoly. The roots are very dense, they may also strangulate other plants while also growing high.